# Use multiple expression in for loop

Tags: go

It is possible to use multiple expression in go loop like:

```
for _, err := range errs; err != nil  {

    }
```

Or I have to do like:

```
for _, err := range errs {
        if err != nil {
         statement
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use multiple error statement in a for range loop? Normally an error is an unique event and need be handled accordingly. If you wish to access as an array value then you need to check for different condition like `switch` or `if` statement.

Comment: Did you look at the language reference before asking the question? You're getting down-voted because your question is not demonstrating that you've made any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

```
ForStmt = "for" [ Condition | ForClause | RangeClause ] Block .
Condition = Expression .
```

You can either have a Condition, *or* a ForClause, *or* a RangeClause. You cannot combine them.